# Stack Bridge Application

Tags: app, c#, .net

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

SB For Windows

[image: Connect to Site]

[image: Select User]

[image: Main]

### About

From This Application you can see all your account, see new Questions and Answer. You will receive a message every time you get a badge etc.

#### License

Version 1.0 will be free.

#### Download

[Installer](http://files.lcp.com.ar/StackBridgeSetup.exe)

#### Platform

.NET First Version Windows Only, then I plan to use Mono to Create a Mac Version. Then a iPad/iPhone/iPod touch version will be released too.

#### Testing

If anyone want to test my app, please contact me or download from the link.

### Contact

- Leonardo Carlos Prada - aka Jedi Master Spooky - lprada@lcp.com.ar
- https://lcp.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W19
- http://lcp.fogbugz.com/

### Code

.NET C#

Comment: Uhm... how are you going to port a .Net app to iPhone?

Comment: You can use the Mono Project and the MonoTouch. Its all depends if Apple allow us or not

Comment: I don't think it fits with Apple's new license.

Comment: I still hope that it will change some how. If not I have a excuse to learn ObjectiveC

Comment: Of course, I'm not saying I agree with Apple in any way.

Comment: @jedi not only an excuse to learn obj-c, but also an excuse to use MSOEngine :)

Comment: @Matt I am learning right Now :)

Comment: I'm currently making an iPhone application for Stack, I've gotten as far as displaying the questions in a tableview, and I'm just perfecting that atm. Displays basically everything you see on the front page of SO, so tags and everything.