# I need Testers, anyone want to be the First?

Tags: discussion, testing

I will be needing testers for  my app ["Stack Bridge"](https://stackapps.com/questions/147/stack-bridge-application). If anyone want to be the first to destroy, I mean test my app, let me know.

Comment: You would probably get more response by putting a link to your app and explaining how you would like it to be tested.

Comment: What does the app entail? Is it a web app or a desktop app?

I'll be glad to test it, as long as I have the necessary hardware/software to do so.

However, I agree with @Nick. You should just post a link here so that everyone can test it and give you feedback.

Comment: I'm up for it... although if this is like Bridge the card game, I'm not sure I'm down with all the lingo.

Comment: Is it Windows-only?

Comment: It looks like a neat app - I'd like to test it. How I would do so, however, is unclear.

Comment: I update the Stack Bridge Page for the download link

Comment: @Lucas have you download the app?

Comment: @Jedi Master: Will do that now - have been a bit busy recently :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he means this: [Stack Bridge Application](https://stackapps.com/questions/147/stack-bridge-application)